# PHP, Two connections, VPN and SSL

Tags: php, soap, ssl, vpn

I need consume two services from two differente providers.

I need connect with one SOAP server (WSDL), this code works correctly,  the server required use SSL, but the problem is, in the same application, we need connect against another server who uses VPN and XML over HTTP, how can make this works correctly.

How separate this two ways of connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your network properly. This is nothing that PHP can influence. All PHP can do is connect via the network to a target server using HTTP or HTTPS. So if the server can ping and connect to both services on the command line (try to download the WSDL or any other resource with wget or curl), it will work.

If not, you have to find out how the servers are to be called (domain names), which IP they have, if the domain name properly resolved to these IPs, and if that IP is actually reachable by network (using a VPN does not really make a difference, it simply is another network connection).

Unfortunately going into these network details is probably beyond the scope of an answer here.